# Apache and Apache Solr together

Tags: apache, solr, apache2

I've got a question: I came across Apache Solr as requirement for a module I'm installing and even after reading the documentation on Apache Solr's official homepage I'm still not sure whether Apache runs alongside regular Apache or does it require it own server? If it does work alongside Apache, is there any known issues/problems that I should be aware of? How would this architecture (Apache and Apache Solr) in terms of file system and serving pages? I'm sorry if the question might sound silly but I'm very new to the whole server-side programming/setup world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to install Tomcat or some other container to install Solr on a Linux box. Tomcat and Solr can be installed along side regular Apache web server, or you can use a different server.

I have done both, installed Solr on same server as well as use different server. Both work fine. It comes down to your scale, requirements, budget and other factors.

In the attached **diagram1** Solr runs under Tomcat on same server as Apache web server[image: Solr basic architecture, running under Tomcat on same server as web server]

In the attached **diagram2** Solr runs under Tomcat on different server than Apache web server. Here we have a separate server for Solr.
[image: Solr basic architecture, running under Tomcat, on different server than web server]

Let me know if you have any more questions about architecture.

Comment: Hey man! thank you for explaining. That makes more sense now. Is there any risk of running Solr and Apache on the same machine (basically for budget reasons I cannot run Solr and Apache in different servers, but I'm worried that I might have any compatibility/other issue while running both at the same time). I understand there would be a performance issue, but that's secondary at the moment. Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: I do not think there is any risk of running them on same machine. I have seen people have both Apache Solr and Apache web server on same machine all the time.

Comment: Performance will depend on: 1)How much content/docs/webpages you index 2)Specs of your server 3) How you configure indexing onto Solr 4)How frequently you update your Solr index 5)Your solr config, caching etc..   Usually Solr is pretty lightweight, and runs extremely fast.

Comment: Hey Aujasvi Chitkara. Thank you for the responses. Much appreciated!